# Securing REST API Using AWS Cognito

Tags: amazon-cognito

I am exploring options for securing a REST based API being called from end-user applications across a variety of platforms, including mobile, web and OTT applications.

The applications have their own optional login process, though users can also use the application anonymously.

We are an AWS shop, and I'm looking for a more general solution using Cognito and Lambda@Edge, likely using a JWT token.

However, I can't quite piece together the options for issuing the JWT token from Cognito, especially given that we are not requiring any form of login. Is there an option using a rotating secret of some form?  Any other options?

Answer (score 0):

In API Gateway you can secure your API with cognito token.

- Create an Authorization method and select the user pool you want to
  use.
- Attach this method to the API you want to secure.
- Now you will need to pass ID TOKEN in header of every call.
- If token is incorrect or expired the API call will fail.

You can read more [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-integrate-with-cognito.html).